# Why I can't put subfigure side by side?

Tags: graphics, subcaption

I'm using subcaption package to make subfigures side by side but it doesn't work. One figure is on the top of the other. Could anyone help?

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering 
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=.5]{NZ}
\caption{Center of earthquake}
  \label{nz}
\end{subfigure}%

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=.5]{KAIK}
  \caption{KAIK station}
  \label{kaik}
\end{subfigure}%

\caption{}
\label{earthquake}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Remove empty line between them.

Comment: welcome to tex.se! just remove empty line between subfigures.  it start new paragraph, so the subfigures can't be in line.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is solved in comments.